# How do i prove this? (Cauchy's theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit-Foote p.96

Exercise 9

> Let $G$ be a finite group divisible by a prime $p$.
>
> Define $S=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_p)\in G^n: x_1\cdots x_n = 1\}$
>
> THen, $S$ has $|G|^{p-1}$ elements.

HOw do i prove this? I don't even know where to start..

Comment: And what does it mean "$\beta$ is a cyclic permutation of $\alpha$"? ($\alpha, \beta \in S$)

Comment: there is a typo: $n$ should be $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix the statement:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order divisible by a prime $p$.
>
> Define $S=\{(x_1,\dots,x_p)\in G^p: x_1\cdots x_p = 1\}$
>
> Then $S$ has $|G|^{p-1}$ elements.

We want to define a bijection
$$
f\colon G^{p-1}\to S
$$
so the claim is proved. Define
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_{p-1})=(x_1,\dots,x_{p-1},(x_1\dots x_{p-1})^{-1})
$$
and verify that $(x_1,\dots,x_{p-1},(x_1\dots x_{p-1})^{-1})\in S$ and that you actually get a bijection.

---

A cyclic permutation of $(x_1,\dots,x_p)$, in this context, is a $p$-tuple of the form
$$
(x_{k+1},\dots,x_p,x_1,\dots,x_{k})
$$
that is, one where the first $k$ terms are removed from the left side and reinserted at the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The only condition is that $x_1\cdots x_p=1$. So, how many choices for $x_1$? (answer:$|G|$). How many choices for $x_2$? (answer: $|G|$).... how many choices for $x_{p-1}$? (same answer). Now, how many choices for $x_{p}$? well, none since the only way for the condition to hold is if $x_p=...$.